# Will Parallels Desktop harm the hardware of my MBP?

Tags: windows, hardware, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I am running VM, PD in particular, on my MBP.

I have encountered several scary things today: machine noise (sounds like "Kah-Kah") occurs while I am in 64-bit Windows 7 in VM.

Will the PD actually harm the hardware of my MBP? The sound is really scary!

Comment: How old is your MBP ? If you have a HardDrive does the sound comes from it ? (AFAIK, PD should not "able" to hard a computer.)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler it is the newest. So I guess it is already SSD. Yeah, exactly! The sound is just like from a hard disk!

Comment: I wonder if there are recorded sounds in Parallels similar to how electric vehicles are now getting recorded engine noises to alert sentient beings that they are in motion.

Comment: @FarticlePilter you have a Retina MacBook Pro ? If so please edit your post.